# How to initialize a CBMutableCharacteristic with multiple CBCharacteristicProperties and Permissions

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm creating a new CBMutableCharacteristic for use in a Bluetooth app I'm making.  I got some code from a tutorial, which looks like this:

`_customCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:characteristicUUID properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];`

where `_customCharacteristic` is my CBMutableCharacteristic.

However, I want to initialize my `_customCharacteristic` with other properties, such as `CBCharacteristicPropertyRead` and `CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite`.  The same is true for the permissions: I want to also give it `CBAttributePermissionsWriteable`.

According to this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/translated_content/CBCharacteristic.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CBCharacteristicProperties

and this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBMutableCharacteristic_Class/Reference/CBMutableCharacteristic.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CBAttributePermissions

I can have both multiple properties and permissions for each characteristic.  However, I don't know how to initialize my CBMutableCharacteristic in this way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Its an enum, whose different values can be ORed bitwisely, so you can use the characteristic properties and permissions together:

```
CBMutableCharacteristic *_customCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:characteristicUUID properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify+CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
 value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable|CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];
```

Comment: It's important to note that this works only because the values are biwise exclusive and each value is added only once. Using the bitwise or "`|`" operation is safer and the generally accepted solution.

Answer (score 5):

tdevoy answer is right one , Or following is also working code for me

```
characteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:characteristicUUID      properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse|CBCharacteristicPropertyRead  value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable|CBAttributePermissionsWriteable];
```

Answer (score 2):

The current answers were valid at the time, but it's been eight years and now Apple uses an `OptionSet` for the **properties** and **permissions**.

The following would be the modern, Swift based approach for initializing a `CBMutableCharacteristic`, and includes a short sample snippet you can run in a playground to verify.

```swift
import CoreBluetooth

let cbuuid = CBUUID()
let characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: cbuuid,
                                             properties: [.notify, .read],
                                             value: nil,
                                             permissions: [.readable, .writeable])
// All print true
print(characteristic.properties.contains(.read))
print(characteristic.properties.contains(.notify))
print(characteristic.permissions.contains(.readable))
print(characteristic.permissions.contains(.writeable))
```