# How to initialize CBMutableCharacteristic with multiple properties in iOS swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

While initializing `CBMutableCharacteristic` how can we add multiple `properties` and `permissions` to it.

```
let customChara = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: Constants.RX_UUID, properties: , value: data, permissions: )
```

I would like to add read & notify as `properties`, but above `function` allows only to add one property. Same in the case of Permission.

I already came across an older solution but it's not working now.[How to initialize a CBMutableCharacteristic with multiple CBCharacteristicProperties and Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114121/how-to-initialize-a-cbmutablecharacteristic-with-multiple-cbcharacteristicproper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to pass an Array of `CBCharacterProperties` to the function's `properties` argument.

```
let customChara = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: Constants.RX_UUID, properties: [.authenticatedSignedWrites,.broadcast], value: data, permissions: .writeable)
```